# Counting fields in a table, with criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

So, I am trying to workout how to calculate counts, based on a table that looks like the below table but with a lot more countries around the world.  -

```
Country1|Country2
   UK   | USA
   UK   | USA
   UK   | USA
   UK   | UK
   USA  | UK
```

I am trying to basically count each field a bit like this, based on the above table

```
Country1|Country2
   1    | 1
   1    | 1
   1    | 1
   1    | 0
   1    | 1
```

And I want it to return -

```
 CountryName | Count
    UK       |  5
    USA      |  4
```

As I mentioned above, this needs to be dynamic and account for any amount of countries. The countries are all named the same, so USA will always been USA and not the united states of america.

THanks!

EDIT- I have attached the query im using to return the rows for more clarity,

```
 Select 
 country1
 country2
 FROM Country1Database c1Db
 join Country2Database c2Db on c1db.MatchID = c1db.MatchID
```

Comment: @forpas, or 5, since there are 5 UK rows.

Comment: I dont understand how the counting work. What mean "bit like this" and how come UK has 5 and USA 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With UNION ALL:

```
select t.country countryname, count(*) counter from (
  select country1 country from countries
  union all
  select country2 country from countries where country2 <> country1
) t
group by t.country
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=66e4e114b16694f926c9fb0a29d7694c)

Comment: . . This would produce "6" for UK.  The question is rather subtle.

Comment: You must add logic to not count twice when the same country is in both columns

Comment: Let me check if this is the case.

Comment: Yes this is the case. I think `where country2 <> country1` fixes it.

Comment: This is not counting for the fact that Uk-UK is only 1 for the uk and not 2! Nice query though

Comment: It is counting only once UK in that case.

Comment: The 2nd part of the UNION does not fetch UK because it is = to country1. So it is counted only in the 1st part of the union.

Answer (score 0):

You want `apply` :

```
select CountryName, count(*)
from table t cross apply 
     ( values (country1), (case when country2 <> country1 then country2 end) 
     ) tt(CountryName)
where CountryName is not null
group by CountryName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . one way is to unpivot and count distinct rows:

```
select v.country, count(distinct seqnum)
from (select row_number() over (select null) as seqnum, t.*
      from t
     ) t cross apply
     (values (t.country1), (t.country2)) v(country)
group by v.country;
```

Another method is to adjust the logic so a country is not counted twice when in the same row:j

```
select v.country, count(*)
from (t cross apply
     (values (t.country1)
             (case when t.country2 <> t.country1 then country2 end) 
     ) v(country)
where v.country is not null
group by v.country;
```

This version should have better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Sample Data

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.SampleData') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE SampleData

CREATE TABLE SampleData (Country1 VARCHAR(20),Country2 VARCHAR(20)  )
INSERT INTO SampleData 
 SELECT 'UK'   , 'USA'  UNION ALL
 SELECT 'UK'   , 'USA'  UNION ALL
 SELECT 'UK'   , 'USA'  UNION ALL
 SELECT 'UK'   , 'UK'   UNION ALL
 SELECT 'USA'  , 'UK'

SELECT * FROM SampleData
```

Sql Script by using UNPIVOT

```
SELECT DISTINCT CountryName,
        COUNT(CountryData)OVER (PARTITION BY CountryName ORDER BY CountryName) AS CountryData
FROM
(
SELECT CountryName,CountryData
FROM
(
SELECT  Country1,
        Country2 
FROM SampleData
)AS SRC
UNPIVOT
(
CountryName FOR CountryData IN ([Country1],[Country2])
) AS Upvt
)dt
```

Result

```
CountryName     CountryData
----------------------------
    UK              6
    USA             4
```